# Screen crazily flashing after custom resolution

Tags: ati, display-resolution

I am using ubuntu 15.10 on A8-7670k APU.
Since `fglrx` is not working (for this APU?), I add a custom resolution setting with built in radeon driver.
I added several line in my startup script `.xprofile`:

```
xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080   1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode VGA-0 1920x1080_60.00
xrandr -s 1920x1080
```

This is working for me, but screen sometimes blink crazily, after booting, and mostly when I open a program.
Can anyone help?

Comment: What does "Not working" mean?

Answer (score 0):

After many tries, fglrx won't work (give me no display output).
Until I changed to Ubuntu 16.04 beta, default driver finally works on 1080p output.